# Отделяется ли запятой "в том числе"?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "В том числе(,) и, если речь идет о...." Вроде как вводный оборот тут стоит в начале предложения и запятыми выделяться не должен. Но меня, как говорится, терзают смутные сомнения)))

Comment: А Вы видите здесь предложение?

Answer (score 1):

Обороты со словами "особенно, в особенности, в частности, в том числе", начинающие собой присоединительные обороты, не отделяются запятой от этих оборотов. ("В том числе и, если речь идет о...." )

Comment: А зачем вообще здесь запятая?

Answer (score 0):

В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ, союз
Присоединительные обороты, начинающиеся союзом «в том числе», обособляются. **Союз «в том числе» не отделяется запятой от стоящих перед ним союзов «а», «и», образуя с ними единое сочетание.**
Приезжает генерал; дрожащий смотритель отдает ему две последние тройки, в том числе курьерскую. А. Пушкин, Станционный смотритель. Я увидел при этом и презенты, полученные графом от княжны, в том числе и ее, столь схожий с императрицей Елисаветой, портрет. Г. Данилевский, Княжна Тараканова. Никогда Федор Никитич, ценивший всё изящное, а в том числе и геометрию, не предполагал, что это прекрасное математическое понятие, обозначающее часть площади криволинейной фигуры, будет так опошлено. И. Ильф, Е. Петров, Золотой теленок. На другой день князь Андрей поехал с визитами в некоторые дома, где он еще не был, и в том числе к Ростовым, с которыми он возобновил знакомство на последнем бале. Л. Толстой, Война и мир. [Здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_129)